# How to continuously display the newest version of an image file on Linux?

Tags: linux, utilities

I need program that reads an image from the disk location `/home/me/image.png`, displays it on the screen in a window and then refreshes the window whenever there is a change to the image located at `/home/me/image.png`.

My preferred program for viewing images is `feh` but `feh` does not have a built-in feature for refreshing itself when the file changes.

One option I considered was writing bash script that kills and reopens `feh` whenever the file changes. But that would display the image in a new window. I want to display the image in its original window.

I tried ImageMagick's `display` utility but it doesn't work on my machine. Maybe I'm using `display` wrong? I used `$ display -update 1 /home/me/image.png`. ImageMagick doesn't give me any errors. It just fails to refresh the image when I write changes to disk.

Refreshing an image when it changes on disk seems like a basic feature lots of image-viewing programs ought to support, but I've tried several image-viewing programs like `feh`, `fim` and `eog` but none of them refresh when the image on disk changes.

## System Specs

My shell is bash. My windowing system is i3. My distro is lubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sxiv` is a simple X image viewer that automatically reloads an image when it is modified. It does not require any special options. Simply launch an image using:

```
sxiv <file>
```

It is available in the Ubuntu repositories under the package name `sxiv`.

Comment: Thank you. `sxiv` does refresh when I press `r` but does not reload automatically when I do `$ cp new-image.png /home/me/image.png`. Does this mean there is something wrong with my system?

Comment: I have tested `sxiv` version 26 on Arch and Ubuntu 21.04 and they all reload automatically when the file changes. You may want to check if you have the latest version.

Comment: You will need at least version 24 of `sxiv` since that is when they introduced the [autoreload feature](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv/commit/edb117e3bdb4d6bef4a4749d94144df8472c0a4d).

Comment: Solved. Building version 26 of `sxiv` from source solved the problem. I was using version 1. Thank you!

Comment: If anyone stumbles on no reload with "sxiv: Could not initialize inotify, no automatic image reloading", having multiple instances of the folder open in Gwenview caused this for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little involved, but you can build a version of `feh` that supports `--auto-reload` using the Ubuntu / Debian tools. I don't know why this isn't enabled by default, frankly.

Install any packages needed to build feh: `sudo apt-get build-dep feh`

Install the package building support: `sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts`

Make a directory to work in: `mkdir src && cd src`

Get the upstream source: `apt source feh`

Chdir with `cd feh-3.6.3` or to whichever directory you have

Edit the debian/rules file to change this line:

```
dh_auto_build --parallel -- PREFIX=/usr exif=1
```

To:

```
dh_auto_build --parallel -- PREFIX=/usr exif=1 inotify=1
```

Build the package: `debuild -us -uc -b`. You can ignore most warnings and even some errors.

Install your shiny new `feh` package: `sudo dpkg -i ../feh_3.6.3-1_amd64.deb`

Now you will have a `feh --auto-reload` option that will automatically reload a file if it changes on disk. And unlike `eog` or `eom`, it will cope with partial or broken files, so if you're updating the file non-atomically (e.g. streaming an image processing program's output to a file) then it won't break and stop showing the file.

You'll probably want to make sure `feh` isn't accidentally upgraded by `apt` - to do this, mark it as "held" with:

`sudo apt-mark hold feh`

You can unmark it in future, should you wish to upgrade to the distro's upstream version, with:

`sudo apt-mark unhold feh`